# How do you choose between stressed 'to be' and unstressed?

Tags: grammar, phonology, weak-forms

I am wondering in which context people stress the "be" in English grammar.

Both [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/be#English) and [Wordrefence](https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/be) have a stressed and an unstressed form in their dictionary.

I know that, for example, the verb "to have" is used in strong form only when used negatively:

> "I have seen her." /aɪ həv si:n hə/

and

> "I haven't seen her." /aɪ hævnt si:n hə/

But for the verb "to be", I can't find an example where we could use it negatively.

Comment: "Death be not proud" (Donne). "Don't be cruel" (Elvis).

Comment: You don't choose it, it chooses you.  It depends entirely on the phrasing of your words, and the emotional impact you are trying to convey.

Comment: "I have seen huh"? "I haven't seen hay"? What are the transcriptions sposta show? Are you asking about stressing _be_ or lengthening it? And which dialect of English are you referring to? The transcription appears to be for RP only.

Answer (score 2):

Your rule for when to use strong or weak form for *has* is incomplete. You also use strong form when the word is emphasized:

> He doesn't drive his car to work, but he has one. (strong form)
>   I have two, but he only has one.  (weak form)

or at the end of a phrase:

> it's the only kind he has.

Both of these cases (and probably others that I've forgotten) are also possible with *be*.

Comment: The use of has was only as an example. The OP is asking about the various declensions of the verb 'to be'.

Answer (score -1):

**A:** "John is not coming with us."

**John:** Oh, **am** I not? We will see about that! I'll be there regardless of what you say! - Emphasised to indicate defiance.

**A:** "And Peter is not coming with us."

**Peter:** Oh, aren't I? What am I going to do then? - Unemphasised